# jQuery .after won't insert <body> element

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this work?

```
var newbody = "<body><div>hello</div></body>";

$("body").remove();
$("head").after(newbody);
```

All i get after that is:

```
</head>
<div>hello</div>
```

How can i get it to stop dropping the body tags?

Comment: Why are you doing `$("body").remove()`?

Comment: Why do you want to disembody your page?

Comment: @BoltClock The Platonic dualism of an HTML page hadn't previously occurred to me, but it's definitely troubling...

Comment: Nice pun, i'm receiving the body from another page (via ajax) and want to replace the current page's body with body i receive from the ajax response. The catch is that they'll have different body classes, so i need to replace the **whole** body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how jQuery's HTML insertion functions work with `before()` and `after()`.  IIRC, they create a temporary element and set the `innerHTML` of the newly created element, before transferring the elements to where they're supposed to be.  Since the `<body>` tag can only be a child of the `<html>` element, the major browsers remove it from the source.  However, when you append elements to the `<html>` element, a new `<body>` element should be implied anyway.

If you're unsure, you could use the standard DOM function `createElement()` to create the body and use `append()` to add the element as a child of `html()`:

```
var newbody = document.createElement("body");
$(newbody).html("<div>hello</div>");
$("body").remove();
$("html").append(newbody);
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3dSN4/** (shows it working with a class name)

That all being said, there aren't really any reasons I can think of for removing and creating a new body element.  You should just manipulate the existing body element in the required manner as to minimize any potential browser issues arising from removing the body.

Answer (score 2):

or Better yet..

```
var newbody = "<body><div>hello</div></body>";
$("body").replaceWith(newbody);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newbody = "<body><div>hello</div></body>";

$("body").html("");
$("body").append(newbody);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xkXQ/

Comment: check the output on the new dom, the class is still "hello" as per original dom